# WebGL not working with Firefox, Intel HD graphics, ArchLinux, and Thinkpad T540p

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, webgl

Is anyone having issues getting webGL to work on Firefox? https://get.webgl.org/ It was working 1-2 months ago, but is now broken. Works fine on Chromium.

I set `webgl.force-enabled;` to `true`, but no luck. Not sure if there are other promising configs - I did a search for "webgl" in the `about:config` page, but I can't find anything promising.

Here is some info on my system:

`[my-pc]/home/me$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 43.0.4
[my-pc]/home/me$ uname -a
Linux my-pc 4.3.3-3-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 08:12:23 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[my-pc]/home/me$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

I also tried starting firefox with `--safe-mode` and with `--profile /path/to/empty/folder` but webGL is still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried multiple webGL sites? For example, this 3D maze screensaver game? https://web.archive.org/web/20130927012857/http://nyhacker.org/~sirtophat/maze/ - that's what I tested and verified it worked with on my GM965 with webgl force enabled.

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple sites. WebGL on your link above doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Software-wise, same setup. Same result. Firefox:  "While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable." Chomium: Everything works fine. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Intel integrated graphics chip, you might have to enable hardware acceleration (i.e. exposing the GPU functionality directly to certain software) for the X.org server of the X11 window system.

To do this edit or create the configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and put the following in there:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true" 
   Option      "DRI"    "3" 
EndSection
```

### Sources

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Configuration
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1595276#p1595276

Comment: This alone didn't work for me, unfortunately. Still trying.

EDIT: This does it: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239480

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1801935#p1801935 suggests to set `security.sandbox.content.read_path_whitelist=/sys` in `about:config`. This does the trick for me as well. Thank you!